# Mongoid: find through Array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've fetched a number of ids through MapReduce. I've sorted those ids by some criteria and now I need to get those objects in this particular order:

```
MyModel.find(ids)
```

Right? But it returns objects not in the order ids are stored. Looks like this is just the same as

```
MyModel.where(:_id.in => ids)
```

which won't return fetched objects in just the same order as stored ids.

Now I can do this

```
ids.map{|id| MyModel.find(id)}
```

which will do the job but it will knock the database many many times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the ordering by hand after you have all your objects. Something like this:

```
ordering = { }
ids.each_with_index { |id, i| ordering[id] = i }
objs = MyModel.find(ids).sort_by { |o| ordering[o.id] }
```

Comment: is it faster then fetching each item from db?

Comment: @fl00r: It should be, just one MongoDB access to fetch the models and a simple sort (with built in Schwartzian Transform) to get things in the desired order. Database access is generally the expensive part. Try benchmarking it, it is hard to guarantee anything without access to real data.

Comment: @muistooshort, I'm facing a similar problem. In general, is it true that it would just be better practice to minimize db hits?

Comment: @Kevin: Usually the fewer database hits the better. Ideally you'd be able to represent the ordering condition in a way that the database could understand, in SQL you'd use an `order by case ... end` to inline the lookup table, MongoDB isn't that flexible so you have to do it yourself outside the database.

Comment: @muistooshort, I'm interested in doing this, but allowing redundant ids to be returned...possible??

Comment: @Kevin: Probably possible but I'm not sure what you exact situation is.

Answer (score 12):

Was working on a similar problem and found a bit more concise solution:

```
objs = MyModel.find(ids).sort_by{|m| ids.index(m.id) }
```

basically just using the sort block to snag the index of the the element.