# Sorting a query in order of an input array using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

We use mongoid in a ruby on rails project and I need a simple user list sorted by the ids I use to find the correct result sets.

So basically something like this:

```
ids = [7, 1, 3]
User.where(:uid.in => ids)
```

This gives a list back sorted by the indexed UIDs.

But it needs to be sorted by the `ids` array.

Is there an easy way to do this with mongoid? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533104/mongoid-find-through-array-of-ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `User.where(:uid.in => ids).order_by(uid: :asc)`

Or use aggregation when sequence important

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
match = { "$match" => {"uid" => {"$in" => ids } } }
field = { "$addFields" => { "__order" => { "$indexOfArray" => [ ids, "$uid" } } }
sort = { "$sort" : { "__order" : 1 } };
User.collection.aggregate([match, field, sort]);
```

Comment: But I want the order by the Array of ids not by uid. Thats the whole point of the problem.

Comment: I've edited a solution, but I need to check

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to keep the result object type because I want to use .only .skip .limit etc. on it and I can't do it with Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation